# How to write Strings to an OutputStream

Tags: java, string, outputstream

How can I create class that takes an implentation of `OutputStream` and writes the the content to it?

For example, the following print method is wrong and will not compile. What are the options or better techniques?

```
public class FooBarPrinter{
    private OutputStream o;
    public FooBarPrinter(OutputStream o){
        this.o=o;
    }

    public void print(String s){        
        o.write(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should 1) look at the OutputStream API and use methods available to it, and 2) if you have an error, post the error here so we don't have to guess what is wrong.

Comment: For instance, the API will show you that there is no OutputStream method called write(...) that takes a String parameter, and so you can't just make one up and expect it to work. Instead you must use the methods that are available.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A generic `OutputStream` doesn't have the ability to write a `String` directly to it. Instead, you need to get the `byte[]` of the `String` and then write them out to the stream.

```
public void print(String s){ 
    o.write(s.getBytes());
}
```

Refer to the [OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) java documentation for more information on the supported write data types.

My suggestion for making this better is to make sure the `OutputStream` you provide in the constructor is a `BufferedOutputStream`, as this will improve the performance of your code. It works by buffering some of the data in memory, and writing it out to disk in big chunks instead of many smaller writes.

Here is the java documentation for [BufferedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html)

Answer (score 9):

I think that the other answers are missing an important point / question.

> Should you really be using an OutputStream?

The `OutputStream` and `InputStream` class hierarchies are for writing and reading byte-oriented data.  But Java Strings are not byte-oriented.  They are character-oriented (to a first approximation), and characters in Java are 16-bit Unicode code units.

When you write characters to a byte stream, the JVM has to do a conversion to *encode* the characters as bytes.  In fact, there are many possible ways to do this.  For example, UTF-8 will encode each character in the sequence as a one *or more* bytes, Latin-1 or ASCII will encode *a subset* of characters as single bytes and turn others into (probably) question marks. And so on.

Now, it is possible to write something like this:

```
  public void print(String s){ 
      o.write(s.getBytes());
  }
```

but it has a problem.  The problem is that the `getBytes()` method on a `String` uses the JVM's default character encoding scheme to do the conversion.  And this (the default encoding scheme) depends on the environment which the JVM was launched.  So that code, does different things depending on the environment.  Now you could fix that by specifying the charset:

```
  public void print(String s){ 
      o.write(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  }
```

but that gets cumbersome if you are calling getBytes in lots of places.

If you are doing a lot of text-based output, a better idea is to use the `Writer` API instead of the `OutputStream` API.  The `Writer` API and its implementations deal with the conversion under the hood ... and more consistently and efficiently.

The final point is that there are other APIs that can be helpful in doing text-based output.

- The `BufferedWriter` class (and also `BufferedOutputStream`) support efficient output by introducing in-memory buffering into the output process.  This saves system calls, especially if you are doing lots of small write operations.
- The `PrintWriter` class provides a whole lot of convenience methods, and also removes the need to handle IOExceptions.  (If an IOException occurs, the `PrintWriter` makes a note of it.  There is a method for testing whether an exception has occurred.  This can be useful or dangerous, depending on what you are doing ...)

Answer (score 2):

To write out strings, take a look at the [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) class. You can see an example of a class that does what you intend [here](https://github.com/codecrafter/orders/blob/master/src/main/java/codecrafter/orders/SimpleReceipt.java).

Also, you can wrap an `OutputStream` using [one of the `PrintStream` constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream%28java.io.OutputStream%29):

```
public class FooBarPrinter{
  private PrintStream p;
  public FooBarPrinter(OutputStream o){
    p = new PrintStream(o);
  }
  public void print(String s){      
    p.print(s);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: note that you can also use the [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) class in the same manner as `PrintStream` above; which is typically better because you can specify the encoding to use, avoiding any platform dependencies.

Comment: It should be noted that a `PrintStream` handles exceptions differently: *"Unlike other output streams, a `PrintStream` never throws an `IOException`; instead, exceptional situations merely set an internal flag that can be tested via the `checkError()` method."*

Comment: @GregKopff: Yes, now it's noted. Thanks!