# Android file writing/reading

Tags: android, file

It's shows me some letters and numbers when i enter a number in the TextField for example i will type 100 and it gives me letter "d" how can i fix this ? I have this code.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int takeMoney = Integer.parseInt(txtEdit.getText().toString());
            String filename = "moneySavings.txt";
            int asd = takeMoney;
            FileOutputStream outputStream;

            try {
                outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputStream.write(asd);
                outputStream.close();
                savings.setText("File Created !");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            FileInputStream fis;
            final StringBuffer storedString = new StringBuffer();

            try {
                fis = openFileInput("moneySavings.txt");
                DataInputStream dataIO = new DataInputStream(fis);
                String strLine = null;

                if((strLine = dataIO.readLine()) != null) {
                    storedString.append(strLine);
                    savings.setText(strLine);
                }
                dataIO.close();
                fis.close();
            }
            catch  (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Explain me whats causes this problem and how do i fix it ... thanks :)

Comment: well actually 100 is the ASCII for d

Comment: That's because you told the program to parse a `String` as an `integer` - so the program is doing what you ask. Maybe you need to remove the `Integer.parseInt` bit if you want to get a `String` back.

Comment: But if i remove that i will cannot write numbers right ?

Comment: Maybe you need to edit your question and describe what you want to do exactly. From reading all your commentaries, it's not clear what you want to do. Note: You can always read a numeric String literal from a file, converted to an integer, and then do some calculation against it. But like I said, rephrase your question and detail your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100 is the [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) for d. Your string value is being type casted to its ASCII value at the `OutputStream`.

You cannot write strings in `OutputStream` directly.
Try:

```
outputStream.write(txtEdit.getText().toString().getBytes());
```

To limit your inputs to numbers, you can specify the keyboard. See the [TextFields documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html).

Ex 1:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/numberInput"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/number_hint"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

Ex 2 - Phone Dialer Keyboard:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/numberInput"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/number_hint"
    android:inputType="phone" />
```

Comment: Okay so is it not possible to type just a numbers in a textfield ?

Comment: Actually this worked but still cannot make to subtraction on two numbers for example `int total = takeMoney + spentMoney;`

Comment: @StefanRafa I would do something like `OutputStream.write(total.toString().getBytes())`

Comment: Cannot make it like that, its shows me error at `total` because i'm using `int` 
`int total = takeMoney + spentMoney;

                try {
                    outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    outputStream.write(total.toString().getBytes());
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }`

Comment: What does the log show? I would guess the error might have to do with whatever the value of total is.

Answer (score 0):

`OutputStream.write(int)` is writing that `int` as byte, so if you write `.write(100)` and later you read as `string` you will get `d` since `100` is the ASCII code for `d`. If you try `101` it then will be `e`.

If you want to save `100` as `"100"` then try:
[How to write Strings to an OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875649/how-to-write-strings-to-an-outputstream)

Comment: and how do i fix that when i will write number to show me the number not the ASCII code ?

Comment: @StefanRafa you just convert the ```int``` to either ```char[]``` or ```String```.

Comment: @StefanRafa try leaving out ```parseInt()``` and use ```String takeMoney```

Comment: But with strings i will cannot take the numbers in the file to make subtraction of another number ...

Comment: I want to make subtraction like `int total = takeMoney + SpentMoney;`

Comment: @StefanRafa well then you can do ```Integer.toString()``` after everything is done with ```int```, and then ```.write(yourString.getBytes())```